# Expressing the closed form of $\sum_{x=1}^{n} x^m$ as an integral of the closed form of $\sum_{x=1}^{n} x^{m-1}$

Tags: calculus, summation

I was playing around with the closed forms of
$$\sum_{x=1}^{n} x$$ and
$$\sum_{x=1}^{n} x^2$$ to then realize that the formula for the sum of squares can be represented as
$$\int_{0}^{n} \left ( x(x+1) + \frac{1}{6} \right ) dx = \int_{0}^{n} \left ( 2 \cdot \left ( \sum_{x=1}^{n} x \right ) + \frac{1}{6} \right ) dx$$
After this, I went looking for more cases where this happens, and turns out that for all the closed forms I could find it holds true that it can be represented as the integral of the previous power's closed form times the current exponent m, and sometimes with a fraction added (to be more precise, the fraction is always $\frac{1}{v}$, with v being the denominator of the closed form). [More examples here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/smjwhtnhmk). Can this be proved to always happen/explain the seemingly erratic fraction additions?

Comment: I don't see where you got your integrals from.

Comment: To be honest, I got them from a simple coincidence. I just noticed that the derivative for the closed form of $\sum_{x=1}^{n} x^2$ was very similar to the closed form for $\sum_{x=1}^{n} x$ and kept going.